# Why does this curl usage work on Windows but not on OSX / iOS?

Tags: ios, windows, macos, curl, basic-authentication

I have a plugin installed on my server that verifies user credentials, responding with, essentially, 'Valid' or 'Invalid'.

On Windows, I can query my server successfully via:

```
curl -X POST REDACTED -H "Authorization: Basic REDACTED" -F username=REDACTED -F password=REDACTED
```

Special, obnoxious note -- the double quotes are required on Windows due to how the command prompt seemingly processes input.

However, I cannot replicate this result on either OSX or iOS. Here, the result is always, incorrectly, 'Invalid'. I assume there is a subtle difference in how the input to curl is being treated by the terminal between OSX and Windows, so the actual HTTP request is somehow different than Windows. So I tried making the HTTP request more directly in Swift:

```
let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", REDACTED, REDACTED)
let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

let url = URL(string: REDACTED)!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = "username=\(String(describing: username.text))&password=\(String(describing: password.text))".data(using: .utf8)
```

And the results are the same; 'Invalid'. There are a few layers between the user supplied information and the outgoing HTTP request, and it's unclear to me where the problem is likely lurking.

I ensured the curl versions were to within a few months of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On *Windows*, the correct form is:
    curl -X POST REDACTED -H "Authorization: Basic REDACTED" -F username=REDACTED -F password=REDACTED

But on *OSX*, the correct form is:
    curl -X POST REDACTED -H "Authorization: Basic REDACTED" -F username=REDACTED -F 'password=REDACTED'

The password field needs to be enclosed in quotation marks.